# How to avoid wrong characters reading UTF-8 emails with Indy 10.6 and Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, email, utf-8, indy

I am reading email with Indy 10.6.1.5187 and Delphi 7.

I have only problems with UTF-8 encoded emails, which translate to wrong characters in the customers computers.

I have read a lot about this problem, but I have not found a solution, except decoding the raw email by myself.

I wonder if there is a way to get correct emails when the sender encodes them in UTF-8.

Thanks.

Comment: We'd need to see more detail. In order to propose a solution I believe that we first need to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**UTF8 string is received like it was an Ansi string. You have to decode it.**

---

You have to receive the message text in an `UTF8String` (aka. `AnsiString` aka `String` in Delphi 7) then convert them from UTF8 to `AnsiString` or (preferably)`WideString`. You can use the `UFT8Decode()` or `Utf8ToAnsi()` function to decode the email body.

If you use the `UFT8Decode()` function, you will still need WideString aware controls to display the received message.

If you use the `Utf8ToAnsi()` function, the result might not contain characters that are not part of the users local codepage.

So you will use something like:

```
var
  ustrEmailBody: UTF8String;
  wstrDecoded: WideString;
begin
  ... 
  // ustrEmailBody now contains the email body
  wstrDecoded := UTF8Decode(ustrEmailBody);
  SomeUnicodeAwareMemo.Text := wstrDecoded;
```

or

```
var
  ustrEmailBody: UTF8String;
  astrDecoded: AnsiString;
begin
  ... 
  // ustrEmailBody now contains the email body
  astrDecoded := Utf8ToAnsi(ustrEmailBody);
  SomeMemo.Text := astrDecoded; // the memo might display '?' in place of unknown characters
```

---

For further information see the documentation of the  `UFT8Decode()` or `Utf8ToAnsi()` functions in the Delphi help.

Comment: Make sure the email's charset actually says UTF-8 before decoding the data as UTF-8. Not everyone in the world uses UTF-8.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - My answer directly addresses the problem stated in the question. John wrote _"I have only problems with UTF-8 encoded emails, which translate to wrong characters in the customers computers."_